Debugging a function which returns the intersection of two linked lists
I tried to solve following Leetcode problem where you have to find the intersection-node of two linked lists, and return it (or null, if there is none).
I know there are simpler solutions than the one I came up with, but I'd like to know whats wrong with my approach:
Let x be the number of nodes between the start of list A and the intersection; same for y and list B. And let z be the distance between the intersection and the end of the lists (see picture).
Let's assume that list A is longer than B, therefore y<x.

If I let two pointers start from the heads of both lists, the pointer of B is going to reach the end while pointer A is still in the list. Both pointers traveled the same distance y+z. Since list A is longer than B by (x+z)-(y+z) = (x-y), pointer A is at the node (y+z)-(x-y) = z-y. Now I save this pointer in the variable "middle" and I let another pointer "newStart" start at the beginning of B. If I let both of them traverse the list, "middle" is going to reach the end after y nodes so pointer "newStart" will be at position y (the intersection).
public static ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB){
        // First iteration
        ListNode firstA = headA;
        ListNode firstB = headB;
        ListNode middle;
        ListNode newStart;
        while (true){
            if (firstA.next==null){
                middle = firstB;
                newStart = headA;
                break;
            }
            if (firstB.next==null){
                middle = firstA;
                newStart = headB;
                break;
            }
            firstA = firstA.next;
            firstB = firstB.next;
        }
        // second iteration
        while (middle != null){
            middle = middle.next;
            newStart= newStart.next;
        }
        return newStart;
    }


However this doesn't work, and I'm having a hard time debugging and understanding whats wrong in my code.

Your maths is off: (y+z)-(x-y) = z-y: that is not true. Look again.

To solve this problem we have to take into consideration the form of the input. According to the leetcode problem the given linked lists have no cycles which means that the only repeated node that you will find is the intersection node. Next, they also mention that we cannot modify the given lists, which discards the method of modifying the node's value to indicate which nodes were visited or not.
Taking the previous points into consideration, there are many ways to solve this problem, however, I'll explain the most efficient one. To efficiently find the intersection point under these constraints, we can leverage a hash table for its fast lookups.
Algorithm:


Initialize: Create an empty hash table called visited.
Iterate with Two Pointers: 
    Set two pointers ptrA and ptrB to the heads of lists A and B, respectively.

    While either ptrA or ptrB is not null:
        If ptrA is not null:
            Check if ptrA exists in the visited hash table.
                If found, it's the intersection point, return ptrA.
                If not found, add ptrA to visited and move ptrA to the next node.
        Do the same for ptrB (check in visited, add if not found, move to next node).
No Intersection: If the loop finishes without finding a match in visited, there's no intersection, return null.



Explanation:
By iterating with two pointers, we traverse both lists simultaneously.
The hash table keeps track of nodes visited from list A.
If a node from list B is encountered that already exists in the hash table (visited from list A), it's the intersection point.
This approach has a time complexity of O(N + M), where N and M are the lengths of lists A and B, due to the single pass through each list and the constant-time hash table operations.
The space complexity is O(N) in the worst case, as the hash table can store all nodes from list A.
